# How to create a `xhr.timeout` polyfill for IE?

Tags: javascript

Currently I use this to prevent error:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
try {
  xhr.timeout = 5e3;
  xhr.addEventListener('timeout', reqListener);
} catch(e){}
```

Of course this is simply removed timeout feature when the browser doesn't support it. I tried:

```
if (typeof xhr.timeout !== 'number') {
  xhr.addEventListener('abort', reqListener, false);
  setTimeout(function(){
    xhr.abort()
  },5e3);
} else {
  xhr.timeout = 5e3;
  xhr.addEventListener('timeout', reqListener);
}
```

Is there a better method?

Comment: You can look into the microsoft examples https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide/performance/xmlhttprequest#event-support, or the jQuery source https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/master/src/ajax, and maybe tag the IE version you are targeting

Comment: @Slai these solutions are identical to mine.